# Odd pumpkin flower

Tags: diagnosis, flowers, flowering, pumpkins

This is something we have never seen. My neighbour has a pumpkin plant which recently started flowering. They were all male flowers till now. But those flowers were all green, not normal yellow flowers.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Has anyone experienced this? Will this plant produce normal flowers or will these flowers produce pumpkins ? Will it be safe to consume those if it produces?
Or, is it better to pull this plant out?

Comment: Wow, that's very unusual I think. A quick internet search on "green pumpkin flowers" turned up nothing (which I'm guessing you already know). I'd love to see what, if any, fruits this plant produces.

Comment: I've never seen it either.

Comment: Did the plant produce fruit? How'd it look?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have observed, some flowers are green to begin with.  Most of the time they turn yellow as they mature.  But I still can't find any references.  Either way, there is nothing toxic about the flowers or the plants,  There is no need to pull them out.

If the plant produces female flowers, then it may produce pumpkins.  A young plant does not always produce female flowers.